# asp:Calendar DateClicked event (not just SelectionChanged)

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, webforms, calendar

I am using the standard `asp:Calendar` control. When a user clicks a date, I am showing a [modal popup](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) by handling the `SelectionChanged` event.

However this means that nothing happens if the user clicks a date, then closes the popup, then clicks the same date again.

I'd rather be handling a `DateClick` event, and do away with the concept of having a selected date altogether.

Can this be achieved using the `asp:Calendar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a workaround:

In the `SelectionChanged` event handler, just call

```
calendar.SelectedDates.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem - I solved it by preventing the user from selecting the currently selected date. I put the following in the `DayRender` event:

```
If e.Day.Date = DateValue(calCalendar.SelectedDate) Then
    e.Day.IsSelectable = False
End If
```